# mysql: connection refused when trying to connect to localhost using remote IP

Tags: mysql

When I try to connect to a local mysql database using it's remote ip-address I get a access denied. When I try to connect to that same database from an external machine, it works without any problems. When I connect to the local database using localhost, it works perfectly as well. E.g., if the database server has the ip 1.2.3.4 then I get the following results:

```
# From the db server
mysql -u username -h localhost -p #works perfectly
mysql -u username -h 127.0.0.1 -p #works perfectly
mysql -u username -h 1.2.3.4 -p #Access denied

# From any other machine
mysql -u username -h 1.2.3.4 -p #works perfectly
```

What can I do to allow local access to my database using its remote ip-address? The OS of the database server is Fedora 15 and the MySQL version is 5.5.23.

Comment: Are you running a firewall? What are the firewall settings?

Comment: "Connection refused" hints at network settings. If mysql denies access, it says so: "ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '1.2.3.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ - I'm running ip-tables, but nothing else. @Olaf - Sorry, I made a mistake: I got `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied`, not connection refused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem myself, but I still don't quite understand why it didn't work:

I granted privileges to that user on the hosts % and localhost:

```
# Before
+-----------------+------------+
| Host            | User       |
+-----------------+------------+
| %               | username   |
| localhost       | username   |
+-----------------+------------+
```

With these settings I got the results I showed above. When I granted privileges to that user on host  it suddenly did work.

```
# After
+-----------------+------------+
| Host            | User       |
+-----------------+------------+
| %               | username   |
| localhost       | username   |
| <myIpAddress>   | username   |
+-----------------+------------+
```

Apparently % does work for remote connections, but not for local connections.

Comment: How did you do that? I'm using command line

Answer (score 15):

Try to edit/add `bind-address = 0.0.0.0` to your `[mysqld]` section of your `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` file and restart *MySQL Service*.

Comment: File doesn't even exist.

Comment: @FeloVilches Try with ```find /etc -name mysqld.cnf``` to locate your config file. If not exist, try to create it at this path as `root` user.

Comment: thanks, this fixed it for me

Comment: This comment helped me 3 years later, thank you very much.

Comment: @EduardoCuomo thanks, this worked for me. but why do we need to do this?

Answer (score -4):

This particular issue can be caused by host name resolution.

I have resolved it in my particular case by deleting this variable from my `my.cnf` config file:

**skip-name-resolve**

Either remark the variable by placing a pound sign `#` or just delete it from your `my.cnf` after making sure you back it up, of course.