# Connection refused when I try to connect via php to mysql database over android app

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

I have a mysql database running on my local machine and I use wamp. I can login with phpmyadmin. Everything looks fine, create tables and users.
When I try to connect with php I get the message connection refused. The same when I try 127.0.0.1/connect.php in my browser. If I have a wrong user in my php file I get the message that user ist wrong.

Here my connect.php

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "users");
    if ($conn) {
        die('no connection: '. mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    echo 'connected';
        mysqli_close($conn);
?
```

I tried everything, localhost, IP, 10.0.2.2, but nothing works. I also checked mysql settings and I read most of the posts here.

Comment: what does `mysqli_connect_error()`says?

Comment: This url " 127.0.0.1/connect.php " works in your desktop and doesn't work on your phone?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032270/mysql-connection-refused-when-trying-to-connect-to-localhost-using-remote-ip) help?

Comment: mysqli_connect_error() says "no connection". In my app error is "connection refused". When I for example put wrong password error is "Access denied for user ..."

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

With this code it works perfect

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "users");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "no connection " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
echo 'conneted';
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```